# SSO Custom Login window isn't opening

Tags: php, single-sign-on, disqus

The SSO custom login window for Disqus isn't opening since recently. It was working fine but doesn't open up now.

http://abmprograms.com/tdr/watch-individual.php?id=16

I found the same issue on another site and the link of it is http://thenextweb.com/socialmedia/2015/03/08/the-29-rules-of-social-media-and-which-ones-to-break/

I emailed this to Disqus support and received the following response,

> To show a single thread across two URLs, you’ll want to use static
>   disqus_urls and disqus_identifiers across both URLs that youd like the
>   thread to appear. Additional instructions may be found here:
>   help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/472095-how-do-i-load-the-same-thread-of-comments-on-multiple-pages-

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: First question when debugging a problem: what changed since it worked last? The answer is very rarely "nothing".

Comment: actually it was something at Disqus's end. I spoke to them and they've fixed it now.

Comment: you should answer the question with the info and then accept the answer (answering your own question is perfectly fine). Or delete the question if you don't think it would be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

In fact it was an issue from Disqus's end. They've sorted it now.